# Check if a worksheet has charts and delete those existing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a project that creates a new chart based on constantly updating information. I simply need to check if a chart pre-exists on a sheet (users could accidently delete previous versions). There seems to be a catch 22 that if a chart doesn't already exist, you can't seem to get the count of the Worksheet.ChartObjects property. I get an Application/Object defined error with the following code:

```
If Worksheets(1).ChartObjects.Count <> 0 Then
        Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Activate
        For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            s.Delete
        Next
        Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Delete
End If
```

It would seem that the count would be 0 if none exist, so how does one test for this? I looked at the Worksheets.Chart object, but that seems to call separate sheets that have only charts in them. I am looking to place a chart on an active sheet. Note I also need to delete each series as I was getting inconsistent results before. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub charttest()
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox "charts on this sheet"
    Else
        MsgBox "no charts on this sheet"
    End If
End Sub
```

This works for me.

**NOTE:**

The line:

```
 Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Activate
```

will fail if Worksheets(1) is not active itself.

Comment: @DeCodened  Your code may try to **Activate** a Chart before **activating** the worksheet on which it resides!

Comment: I tried adding this code 
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate' before that call.
I also tried to go to the actual sheet's page and ensured that page was visible calling ActiveSheet. That didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @DeCodened  Have you tried my code exactly as posted??

Comment: @DeCodened  I am completely puzzled....I am using Excel 365....I tested the code on a completely empty worksheet and then on a worksheet in which I inserted a single chart............I got no errors in either case.................

Comment: I can also mention that this seemed to be working for a while. I don't know what exactly happened. I tried adding a chart, and all of a sudden this call is having issues. I am suspecting there is some funky setting that might be off by hitting the wrong function key, and that is what I am trying to research. I am also not able to select columns....so that is odd